# How to remove some html tags?

Tags: html, regex, vbscript

I'm trying to find a regex for VBScript to remove some html tags and their content from a string.

The string is,

```
<H2>Title</H2><SPAN class=tiny>Some
text here</SPAN><LI>Some list
here</LI><SCRITP>Some script
here</SCRITP><P>Some text here</P>
```

Now, I'd like to EXCLUDE `<SPAN class=tiny>Some text here</SPAN>` and `<SCRITP>Some script here</SCRITP>`

Maybe someone has a simple solution for this, thanks.

Comment: What's the string? It seems to have, you know, done what it does with HTML, and not displayed the tags.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick in VBScript:

```
Dim myRegExp, ResultString
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "<span class=tiny>[\s\S]*?</span>|<script>[\s\S]*?</script>"
ResultString = myRegExp.Replace(SubjectString, "")
```

`SubjectString` is the variable with your original HTML and `ResultString` receives the HTML with all occurrences of the two tags removed.

Note: I'm assuming `scritp` in your sample is a typo for `script`.  If not, adjust my code sample accordingly.

Comment: +1 despite it being dangerous to manipulate HTML with REs at all because HTML isn't a Regular Language. Working with the DOM tree is far better, but a totally different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a lot easier [using css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp):

```
span.tiny {
    display: none;
}
```

or using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
$("span.tiny").hide();
```

Comment: That won't remove the script tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
$(function(){
$('span.tiny').remove();
$('script').remove();
})
```